# Is there any way to move trophies and save data between accounts in one PS3?

Tags: psn

I have two accounts in my PS3, one for playing and another one for use online. I want to move the game saves and trophies from the playing account to the online and get rid of it. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot move trophies from one account to another.  The account is intended to represent *you* and your achievements.  If you were allowed to transfer trophies, you could theoretically sell your trophies to people for real money, which would introduce a problem for Sony.

You **can** transfer trophies to another console, which works just by moving your account to the new console.  The trophies are linked to your PSN identity and should load with no problems in that case.

**Edit:** Totally missed the save data part of the question.  [According to PS3Explained.com](http://ps3explained.com/beginner/users-accounts-and-sub-accounts/), it seems that PS3 saves are specific to user accounts. PS1 and PS2 saves are shared by every user on the system.  However, a user in [this Playstation.com thread](http://boardsus.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-General/Moving-save-data-to-other-account-Possible/m-p/43029505) encountered a message that said he was attempting to copy saves to another account when he was attempting to copy saves between consoles. Since he received it seemingly as an error message, it seems you can't copy saves either.  Someone with more experience with this might be able to give you a more thorough answer though.

References for trophy moving:

- [Neoseeker Forums](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/30444/t1414258-transferring-trophies-linking-accounts/)
- [PS3 Trophies Forums](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/general-ps3-discussion/4343-how-2-sync-trophies-2-new-account.html)

Comment: And the save data? can't be moved either?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. I edited my answer to hopefully address it accurately.  I'm not experienced with this though, so it's based on forum discussions and third-party websites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the 'PS3 explained' site, i didn't know it!

Answer (score 4):

Ok I figured it out!

My husband and I have two accounts but all of our Little Big Planet data was on his account. So first I went into mine and made sure any LBP data was deleted (so as not to confuse the system). Then I logged into my husbands, went to the pod, hit start and profile settings, then made a backup of his data. Then I went to his data settings outside the game, hit triangle for options on the LBP backup and told it to copy to my account. Then logged back into mine, went to pod, start, profile settings, and import. It copied his data to mine and loaded our pod.

Then I was met with a message that since the profile was copied, I won't be able to earn trophies. It tells me to go into back into the data settings and delete the copied file (on my account) and reboot. Of course when you delete it from the game data utility section like it tells you, you delete it completely. So it's up to you--if having trophies means that much to you.

Comment: Since another user unable to comment posted an answer asking this, I'll ask in a comment for him: What do you mean by pod?

Comment: I assume that the pod is the the place where you select the level you want to play, the one with the PS3 controller.

Answer (score 1):

The only way available that I know of is to create a sub account under your main account amd sync it with the server, then login with your sub account details and sync back the trophies data. However, I think Sony has limited the use of that method after PSN was hacked this April.

Comment: Sounds interesting, have you any link or reference to support this or it is a personal experience?

Comment: it's from personal experience...but it also depends on the games, some games you cant move the trophies at all...and such trophies are dependable on your main account.

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy other users' trophies, but on some games (like GTA 4) you can copy saved games.

Not every game allows you to do so. Examples: Infamous, God of War, Black Ops and other games.